# What about using cedar for toy puzzles and blocks?

Tags: wood

Can cedar be used for making wooden puzzles and blocks for children?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The basic answer is yes of course you can, but please expand your query to include your specific concern(s) here so that Answers can be more directly focussed.

Comment: Also: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/search?q=toys

Comment: It's not toxic enough to worry about, but it will split easily.